# How to get row value from wpdb

Tags: wpdb

I want to echo 'yes' if the "notification" row value is 1

I tried to do with this code:

```
global $wpdb;
    $row =$wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_users");
    if($row['notification'] == 1){
echo 'yes';
}
```

Comment: Do you want to do this check for a currently logged in user? Currently, your SQL query pulls all of the users from wp_users table.

Comment: In your code `$row` is array of objects. To get for example login field from first result you should use `$login = $row[0]->user_login;`. Look [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results), `get_results()` returns **array** of objects or **array** of arrays. And the second thing, in [users  table](https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_users) there is no column `notification`.

Answer (score 0):

As @nmr says, $row is an array of objects. You'll need to foreach these - and do the check in the foreach like this:

```
foreach ($row as $item) {
    if($item->notification == '1') {
        echo 'Yes';
    }
}
```

And there's no "notification" column as far as I know.

Also, can you explain what you're trying to achieve? Maybe there's an easier way to achieve your goal.

Best regards